# Adding custom auto-comments to new functions or logic statements in Netbeans 7.3.1 (java)

Tags: java, netbeans

I've recently started working on a project with someone and he prefers the code to be commented in a very particular manner. Instead off adding it all by hand I was wondering if Netbeans had any way to add custom comments to new functions and logic statements. 
The comments added would be backslashes after a closing bracket and then the name of what it's closing. 
For example:

```
public void funcA(int arg){
   if(arg>2)
   {
      System.out.println("hi");
   } //if
} //funcA
```

I looked around but all I could find was creating your own code template for a new class, which isn't what I need. Any help? thanks.

Comment: Brrrr.... Maybe you could find another colleague to work with? Proper indentation and keeping methods short makes this completely superfluous (and IMO those comments reduce readability with useless clutter).

Comment: See also: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/53274/comments-at-end-of-code-block-after-good-or-bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is consistently indented as in your question, you can manage with a regular expression like this:

Capture:

```
(?s)^(\s*)if.*?\1\{.*?\1\}
```

Replace:

```
$0 //if
```

Where the `(?s)` at the start turns on single-line mode (meaning dots match newlines), and the backreferences ensure that the if statement and braces match in indentation and are therefore matching.